# How to place a toolbar button to the right of the heading label?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, dojo

I have a dojox.mobile.Heading added to a dojox.mobile.ScrollableView. This works great, and I have a back button on the heading working as well. I am trying to add a toolbar button to the right of the heading label, but it is displayed on the left of the label, after the back button:

```
    var heading2 = new dojox.mobile.Heading({
        id: "appListHeader",
        label: "?", // placeholder, replaced when device is selected.
        back: "Devices",
        moveTo: "deviceList"
    });

    var button = new dojox.mobile.ToolBarButton ({
        moveTo: "settingsView",
        icon: "../images/settings.png"
    });
    button.placeAt(heading2,"last");
```

[image]

Comment: No advice here? Anyone from dojo (Yoshiroh, Michael??) monitoring this thread?? I thought that the declarative and programmatic interfaces would be functionally symmetrical - perhaps this is not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use "dojo/dom-style" as shown below by using the domNode of the button.

```
require(["dojo/dom-style"], function(domStyle){
  domStyle.set(button.domNode, {float:"right"});
});
```

placeAt(last) puts it at the end of the widget, I assume.

```
button.placeAt(heading2,"last");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would like to use the other syntax for loading and using, but it doesn't like my syntax. In my .html file I have `dojo.require("dojo.dom-style");` in a script tag, and then I tried this but getting errors: `dojo.dom-style.set(button.domNode, {"float":"right"});`. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, figured it out. A poor choice for the module name `dom-style`, as it forces you to use: `dojo['dom-style']` instead of `dojo.dom-style`

Comment: dojo.require("dojo.dom-style") is the pre-AMD syntax. The new AMD syntax uses a slash (/) for module names. The require expects an Array of modules as the first parameter that needs to be loaded/required. Hence the square([]) brackets.